# Credit card payment using paypal in Iphone application

Tags: iphone

I want to implement like this application

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paypodd/id341546114?mt=8

Different kind of credit card payment through PayPal in my native iPhone application. I searched, most documents in paypal sites, they are showing, I need to entry paypal account/email address also to transact. But upon the application, I can see, directly he entered only credit card name, careditcard type, cvv and amount for his transaction?

Anybody any idea? How i implement this??

Comment: some related discussion is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805324/what-options-are-available-to-accept-credit-card-payments-through-an-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That application is using the PayFlow Pro merchant API:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowpro

Note that PayFlow Pro requires an existing merchant account -- you can't just use it to send money to your Paypal account. (This is probably why the iOS application you linked to has had poor reviews: the description doesn't make it clear that the application is useless on its own.)

Comment: Can you give me some questions answer? Say

Comment: Can you give me some questions answer? Say 1. I have a merchant account  2. My customer is paying money in through this application (using credit cards). 3. Instantly, will I get reply from that merchant account that this customer has paid money to my account? So that I can give instantly permit him to buy something.    Final question is, using credit cards , customers will able to pay money to my paypal account, if so, then which API should i use. or can you give me example for iphone application example reference.?