# options for paying for item through iPhone

Tags: iphone, paypal, payment-gateway

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I'm looking at different ways a user could pay for a physical good through an iPhone (similar to [What options are available to accept credit card payments through an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805324/what-options-are-available-to-accept-credit-card-payments-through-an-iphone) but answer is over 3 years old).

For example, if you wanted to order a pizza and just have a web interface. Is it possible to just have a users login credentials and run that as a payment through like paypal? Would this be violating Apple's TOS regarding in-app purchases (I don't think so)? Is there a way to just have it bill to their cell phone account? NCF wouldn't really be an option since it would have to have some distance.

thx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PayPal virtual terminal if you feel like paying so much per transaction.  Really you could use any payment processor over the safari browser [Stripe](https://stripe.com) is good too.  I would recommend Stripe if you need an easy API.

Comment: have heard good things about stripe. prob a model like the amazon payment system meets stripe. any experience with a ios shopping cart system?

Comment: No, I don't.  I've only heard about Stripe with via Ruby on Rails development.